# Why am I not getting the exported Object when importing in another Typescript project?

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs, storybook, javascript-import

I'm trying to create a React component library written by means of Typescript that shall be imported into another Typescript project. To be precise, I would like to import an Analytics chart library into a [storybook](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook) for demo and testing purposes.

To do that, I use these dependencies for the library:

- "typescript": "^3.1.6"
- "webpack": "^4.15.1"
- "babel-loader": "^8.0.4"
- "ts-loader": "^5.3.0"
- "@babel/core": "^7.1.5",
- "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.5",
- "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
- "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
- "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.5",
- many more...

And I these additional dependencies for the storybook:

- "@storybook/react": "^4.0.4"
- all the others mentioned above
- many more...

Moreover, I have this settings in the tsconfig.json of my library:

- "module": "esnext",
- "moduleResolution": "node",
- "target": "es5" (this is on purpose)
- etc.

Webpack generates a neat d.ts file which (among other things) contains:

```
declare module 'mylibrary' {
     import { BarChartFactory } from 'mylibrary/factories/barChartFactory';
     import { LineChartFactory } from 'mylibrary/factories/lineChartFactory';
     import { PieChartFactory } from 'mylibrary/factories/pieChartFactory';
     import { AreaChartFactory } from 'mylibrary/factories/areaChartFactory';
     import { RadarChartFactory } from 'mylibrary/factories/radarChartFactory';
     import { ScatterChartFactory } from 'mylibrary/factories/scatterChartFactory';
     import { GaugeChartFactory } from 'mylibrary/factories/gaugeChartFactory';
     import { HeatmapChartFactory } from 'mylibrary/factories/heatmapChartFactory';

     const Analytics: {
         "barChart": typeof BarChartFactory;
         "lineChart": typeof LineChartFactory;
         "pieChart": typeof PieChartFactory;
         "areaChart": typeof AreaChartFactory;
         "radarChart": typeof RadarChartFactory;
         "scatterChart": typeof ScatterChartFactory;
         "gaugeChart": typeof GaugeChartFactory;
         "heatmapChart": typeof HeatmapChartFactory;
     };
     export default Analytics;
}
```

Last but not least, the libraryTarget is UMD.

Now, when I try to import the library in the storybook like this:

```
import * as Analytics from "mylibrary";
```

and then make a

```
console.log(Analytics)
```

I get

```
Module
    Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
    __esModule: true
    __proto__: Object
```

in the console. This is not exactly useful, because *what I expect is an Object that I can consume (as defined in the d.ts).*.

So, I must be doing and / or misunderstand something fundamentally wrong about exports and imports. I appreciate it very much if somebody could point to the right direction. Let me know if any more details are needed.

Thanks a lot

Walter

EDIT:
[Minimal project setup](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/805e2c044bc7d95a3c773a7fd895d81a20181114211143/fa2177)

- In the folder "analytics", run "yarn install && yarn run dist"
- Go to folder "storybook" and run "yarn install && yarn start-storybook"
- Open a browser and go to localhost:6006
- Check the dev console
- Look out for a message that starts with "There you go!"
- I expect that there is an Object holding all the Analytics factories, rather than a Module or undefined...

Comment: This is going to be tough for me to reproduce based on the information you've provided.  Can you publish a repository that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hi Matt
I'm afraid the project is not open source and therefore, I cannot simply publish a link to the repository here. However, I am happy to provide you with any details you might need, such as the webpack.conf.js or the like...

Comment: I wasn't asking for the original repository, just for one that reproduces the same problem; you can remove all but the minimum amount of code needed to demonstrate the problem.  I know this will take some work for you, but if you do it, I think I have a good chance of being able to find and solve the problem, whereas I'm not willing to spend the time asking you for more details one at a time, so decide whether it's worth it to you.  Or you can wait and see if someone else is willing to help.

Comment: All right. I attached a minimal setup and instructions above. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that you have enabled static code splitting on `analytics`, so Webpack generates two bundles, `vendors~Analytics.chunk.js` and `Analytics.js`.  `Analytics.js` is dependent on `vendors~Analytics.chunk.js`; for an import of `Analytics.js` to return a useful value, you would have to manually load `vendors~Analytics.chunk.js` first.  You could do so by adding the following to `storybook/stories/1_overview.stories.tsx` before the import of `analytics`:

```
import "analytics/vendors~Analytics.chunk";
```

But I don't see what you are hoping to gain in this scenario by having code splitting enabled and having all users of the `analytics` library do this extra import.  I'd suggest turning off code splitting by removing the following from `analytics/webpack.config.ts`:

```
splitChunks: {
  chunks: "all"
}
```